# Experimental results summarized in a single large table OR smaller tables with subset of results?

Tags: peer-review, paper-submission, writing-style, experiment-design

In my experiment, I have obtained a large chunk of results for many different problems being effectively solved by my implemented hypothesis.

If I keep my results as subsets for each problem, then I get 12 tables. But, if I summarize them in a single table, then the large table might span across 2-pages (even in [sidewaystable in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/318322/table-rotation-with-sidewaystable))

I seek some advice on

- Whether reviewers would like to see a large table as described above? (or)
- Should I keep the results individually as per problems?

As per my reviewer experience, both are okay as long as they optimally convey the outcome of the experiment.

Comment: This is fairly opinion-based, but I personally would certainly *not* want to see all results of a paper in a single 2-page table. That being said, consider that there may be better ways to present your data in addition to "one huge table" or "many tiny tables". Maybe you can find instructive visualizations in addition to, or instead of, some tables? Maybe you want to aggregate some data and put the detailed tables into an appendix or into an artifact repository?

Comment: @xLeitix Yes. I had a similar plan. I will put a statistical summary in place and move all results to Appendix or Supplementary materials. Should I delete the question? Yes, I feel the same that it will be purely opinion based.

Comment: I agree with the previous commenter: Consider creating figures instead of tables.

Answer (score 1):

Could you divide your results between a main paper and supplementary material? You could then have the big table in the supplementary material and show the important/relevant extracts in the main paper.

Alternatively - could present your results in a figure? A lot of readers prefer that as it makes it easier to understand.

Answer (score 1):

The important point when presenting results is to keep your reader interested and fully abreast of what you're doing.

Using one large table spread across two pages is a lot of information for anyone to take in at once, and people would more likely skip over it than try to understand exactly what it is you're doing.

I feel the best approach would be to break the tables down into a problem by problem basis, signposting the whole way for your reader so they can follow exactly what it is you're trying to show them before maybe bringing it all together in a concluding section.